# format string java

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting

I need to change a string from the following format "6254897283" to the following format
 " (625) 555-1212." Any ideas for the best way to do this? I will do it in a method that I would like to reuse.

Answer (score 2):

```
String phone = "6254897283";

MessageFormat phoneFmt = new MessageFormat("({0}) {1}-{2}");
String[] phoneArr = { phone.substring(0, 3), phone.substring(3, 6),
        phone.substring(6) };

System.out.println(phoneFmt.format(phoneArr));
```

Or

There is this open source library http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `replaceAll` and regular expressions to accomplish that:

```
String s = "6254897283";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3"));
// (625) 489-7283
```

The idea is to *divide* and capture three groups of 3 (`$1`), 3 (`$2`), and 4 (`$3`) digits from the original 10-digit number, and then re-format these groups accordingly (`($1) $2-$3`).